# Does any von Neumann algebra have $\sigma$-finite projections?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of $\sigma$-finite projections of $M$. In Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebras II", chapter 7, p51, in the proof of theorem 1.11 the equivalence $(i)\iff (iii)$, it is claimed that if $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a maximal family of orthogonal projections in $\Sigma$, then
$$\sum_{i \in I} p_i = 1.$$

Of course, this begs the questions: does a von Neumann algebra even have $\sigma$-finite projections?

Recall that a projection $p\in M$ is called $\sigma$-finite iff $pMp$ is $\sigma$-finite, i.e. any family $\{p_j\}$ of orthogonal projections such that $p_j\le p$ for all $j$ is necessarily at most countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any von Neumann algebra $M$, we can write $I=\sum_jp_j$ with each $p_j$ a $\sigma$-finite projection. The way to achieve this is by taking $\{p_j\}$ to be a maximal pairwise orthogonal family of cyclic projections.

First, it is clear that $\sum_jp_j=I$. For if $q\leq I-\sum_jp_j$ we take nonzero $x\in qH$ and take $q_0$ to be the projection onto $M'x$. Since $qM'x=M'qx=M'x$, we get $qq_0=q_0$, so $q_0\leq q$. The projection $q_0$ is cyclic and orthogonal to all $p_j$, contradicting the maximality of the family.

It remains to show that a cyclic projection $p$ is $\sigma$-finite. We have that $pH=\overline{M'x}$ for some $x\in pH$. Let $\{p_\alpha\}$ be a pairwise orthogonal family of subprojections of $p$. We have  $$\overline{M'p_\alpha x}=\overline{p_\alpha \,M'x}.$$
As $M'x$ is dense in $pH$ and $p_\alpha$ is continuous, then $p_\alpha M'x$ is dense in $p_\alpha pH=p_\alpha H$. Thus we get that $\overline{M'p_\alpha x}=p_\alpha H$. So each $p_\alpha$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $p_\alpha x$. This guarantees that each $p_\alpha x\ne0$. Now, since $\sum_\alpha p_\alpha\leq p$,
$$
\sum_\alpha \|p_\alpha x\|^2=\Big\|\sum_\alpha p_\alpha x\Big\|^2\leq\|px\|^2=\|x\|^2<\infty.
$$
This shows that only countably many indices $\alpha$ can exist, as $\|p_\alpha x\|>0$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: Your answer shows that if $\varphi$ is a weight such that $\varphi(p) < \infty$ for a projection $p$, then $M$ has $\sigma$-finite projections, right? Also, Why is $\varphi(q_0)= \infty$ for every $q_0 \le q$? (I suppose we need to exclude $q_0=0$, and I don't even see why this is the case for $q=q_0$).

Comment: Yes. And if $\varphi(q_0)<\infty$ for nonzero $q_0$, then $\{p_j\}$ is not maximal.

Comment: Thanks! I see that $\sigma$-weak lower semicontinuity on $qMq$ is obvious and that we also have $\sigma$-weak lower semicontinuity on $(1-q)M(1-q)$ by the the proof in Takesaki (because we have that $\{p_i\}$ is maximal in $(1-q)M(1-q)$ as well, and in this VNA they sum to $\sum_i p_i = 1-q$, which is the identity of this VNA). However, how does semicontinuity on both $qMq$ and $(1-q)M(1-q)$ imply semicontinuity of the entire weight?

Comment: Good point. I have rewritten the anwer in a way that avoids all those problems.

Comment: Thanks! What is a cyclic projection?

Comment: A projection $p\in M$ is cyclic if there exists $x\in H$ such that the range of $p$ is $\overline{ M'x}$. Takesaki defines this in V.1.9.

Comment: Is there a W*-algebraic definition? I.e. not depending on the underlying Hilbert space?

Comment: No. I don't think it makes sense. There is very little von Neumann algebra theory you can do that is not spatial.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is it normal that I am not able to fill in these details in Takesaki's book though and should I take a step back and revisit the basics?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, it took me a while to make this answer whole; and that's only because I found the ideas in Kadison-Ringrose (which I know way better than Takesaki). In any case, most of your questions and observations have looked insightful to me.

Comment: It is just that reading Takesaki is sometimes a bit discouraging (but definitely worth it in the end!). Maybe Kadison-Ringrose is an easier read though?

Comment: There are a few concrete points where I prefer Takesaki, but overall I prefer Kadison-Ringrose (which like I said I know way better, so there is an unavoidable bias there). There are other texts that are better for a first read, depending on what the goal is.

Comment: Perhaps again trivial: Why is $\overline{M'p_\alpha x}= p_\alpha\overline{M'x}?$ I can't prove this, as it seems to require that a projection sends closed subspaces to closed subspaces, which is false.

Comment: Good catch. You are right, but it works with a little care in this case. I have included it in the argument.

Comment: Thanks again :)